# Angular: Delete Components, Inside Forms, and Elements with NgIf?

Tags: javascript, css, angular, typescript, angular8

How do I delete Dom elements and Components with *NgIf or any Ng Function?

I have a dropdown list; depending on dropdown, it will display different forms. When person changes the Dropdown Type and then returns later to same dropdown type- the previous form data still Exists, When it should be Cleared.

What is the best way to delete all forms, variables, and the component itself when dropdown changes?

See statement below,

```
<div class = "addressformtotal">
    <div class = "addressblock">
        <app-address-formatheader-form></app-address-formatheader-form>
        <div *ngIf="formatMessage?.addressFormatDescription.includes('Standard')"><app-address-mailing-standard-form></app-address-mailing-standard-form></div>
        <div *ngIf="formatMessage?.addressFormatDescription.includes('Military')"><app-address-mailing-military-form></app-address-mailing-military-form></div>
        <div *ngIf="formatMessage?.addressFormatDescription.includes('Post')"><app-address-mailing-pobox-form></app-address-mailing-pobox-form></div>
        <div *ngIf="formatMessage?.addressFormatDescription.includes('Free')"><app-address-free-form></app-address-free-form></div>
        <div *ngIf="formatMessage?.addressFormatDescription.includes('Rural')"><app-address-mailing-rural-form></app-address-mailing-rural-form></div>
        <div *ngIf="formatMessage?.addressFormatDescription.includes('International')"><app-address-mailing-international-form></app-address-mailing-international-form></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: best way is to data bind to a list (forms and model)

Comment: hi @pixelbits im not trying to data bind but delete, feel free to write in answer or stackblitz, and I can send points, thanks

Comment: where is the dropdown in your code?

Comment: when you data bind to a list, all the components/elements/forms get destroyed automatically

Answer (score 1):

I think that yours inner components (app-address-mailing-standard-form, app-address-mailing-military-form...) can has a @Input about formGroup and *ngIf

```
@Input()group:FormGroup

<form *ngIf="group" [formGroup]="group">
    <input formControlName="prop1">
     ...
</form>
```

So, your main.app can be like

```
<app-address-formatheader-form 
         [group]="form.get("header")>
</app-address-formatheader-form>
<app-address-mailing-standard-form 
         [group]="form.get('mailing')">
</app-address-mailing-standard-form>
<app-address-mailing-standard-form 
         [group]="form.get('military')">
</app-address-mailing-standard-form>
...
```

So, if your main.app create the form like

```
this.form=new FormGroup({
   header:new FormGroup({...}),
   military:new FormGroup({...})
})
```

Only show "header" and "military", but it's only an idea. All depends what the way and where you create the form and the formGroup.

If you create the fromGroup inside the components use a setter in the input like

```
@Input() set visible(value)
{
    if (visible)
       this.group=new formGroup({...})
}
```

And only pass as argument the "visible"

```
<app-address-formatheader-form [visible]="variable"></app-address-formatheader-form>
```

again the form like

```
<form *ngIf="group" [formGroup]="group">
    <input formControlName="prop1">
     ...
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say use reactive forms so that you can form-reset. It's not two way binding so you can control your data much better this way.

So on dropdown change, ngIf will create a new reactive form that will have no data in it.

Check how to create reactive forms [here](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms)

My guess on what is happening, is that you bind with data given from a shared component (the parent) that the children change due to two way binding and so remain unchanged.

Comment: Ok, then I'd need some more code of your ts and at least one of the components to try to figure this out. The components get recreated any time their respective ngIf is set to true, so it must be something you have changed in the data in the meantime.

Comment: Do you set any data in your source data when your user edits one of the forms?